# Conociendo un constructor de conversión

Tags: c++

estoy mirando a qué se refiere cuando se crea un constructor de conversión, que en teoría **es un constructor que convierte el parámetro que recibe en un nuevo objeto distinto al tipo de la clase**.

La cuestión es que no comprendo muy bien este constructor.
¿Alguien podría ponerme un ejemplo más claro?
Lo que he encontrado más o menos es:

```
class B
{
public:
  B(const C& d) {..}
  //..
}
```

Y no me sigue quedando claro, entonces ¿es un constructor que convierte por ejemplo un entero en un objeto de por ejemplo tipo carácter?

Gracias y un saludo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Es un constructor que convierte el parámetro que recibe en un nuevo objeto distinto al tipo de la clase.

Lo has entendido mal. Es un constructor que permite convertir un tipo de dato al objeto que estás programando; por ejemplo:

```
struct I {
    I(int){};
};
```

El objeto `I` tiene un constructor que recibe `int`, lo que significa que puedes convertir un `int` en un `I`:

```
I i = 1; // Convierto '1' en un objeto 'I'
```

O incluso pasar enteros a funciones que reciben un `I`:

```
void funcion(I a, const I &b) {}

// Se convierte '1' en el parametro 'a' de tipo 'I'
// Se convierte '2' en el parametro 'b' de tipo 'I'
funcion(1, 2);
```

Tal vez te estabas confundiendo con el operador de conversión, que permite que tu objeto sea convertido en otro tipo de dato:

```
struct X {
    // Los objetos de tipo 'X' se pueden convertir a 'int'
    operator int() { return 42; }
};

X x;
std::cout << (int)x; // Imprime 42
```

> ¿Y si pongo en el constructor explicit lo que le estoy diciendo es que en el caso de llamar a la función `funcion(1,2)` que de error de compilación (que no haga la conversión)?. ¿Es así?

Correcto. Dado que `I` dispone de un constructor que recibe un `int`, puede usarse para convertir `int` en `I` al llamar `funcion(1, 2);`, esto recibe el nombre de "*conversión implícita*", porque de manera implícita estás convirtiendo un `int` en `I`. Si haces que el constructor de conversión de `int` a `I` sea explícito, le pides al compilador que no haga conversiones implícitas y como bien has señalado: fallará.

Comment: Gracias! ¿Y si pongo en el constructor explicit lo que le estoy diciendo es que en el caso de llamar a la función funcion(1,2) que de error de compilación (que no haga la conversión). ¿Es así? @Paula_plus_plus

Comment: La palabra clave explicit obliga a que para hacer dicha conversión tengas que ser explícito, así que mientras seas explícito puedes seguir usando tu función de conversión. Es decir tu llamada se queda en funcion(1, I(2) ) porque funcion(1,2) ya no funciona.